# How can I rasterize all of the text in a PDF?

Tags: linux, pdf, pdftk, ocr

You know when you have a pdf, which is a scan of a document and it's a really huge file, because it just stores the picture of the scanned document?

And there are OCR tools which can help you to make a proper document which just stores the text?

Well, I need the reverse of that! Let's say I have a perfect pdf document generated with `pdflatex` and I need to turn it into such a "huge" pdf, which looks exactly the same when printed on paper (with a certain dpi value), but is just a picture of the original.

My initial idea is to turn the pdf into a series of JPGs and then back into a PDF, but perhaps there is some canonical way for that?

---

In case you wonder why I would want to do such a thing: I'm currently stuck with a network printer, which is not maintained by me, and which randomly drops characters in printed files! So until someone figures out what's wrong there, I want this as workaround.

Comment: Basically you want to convert Latex or PDF to JPG/PNG files. And print that. (Just a simplification of what you wrote.)

Comment: But I want to still store a document with multiple pages in a single file, so that I can use the features of my pdf viewer, e.g. print 2 document pages on one paper page and so on. I imagine this to be cumbersome with loose PNG files.

Comment: GhostScript can render PDFs into PNG.

Comment: Same question on SuperUser: [How to distill / rasterize a PDF in Linux - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/802569/how-to-distill-rasterize-a-pdf-in-linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could test out if image based PDF's are polluted as well. First convert PDF to (multipage) TIFF, e.g. with [ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/):

```
gs -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -o sample.tif sample.pdf
```

Then convert the TIFF to PDF, e.g.:

```
tiff2pdf -z -f -F -pA4 -o sample-img.pdf sample.tif
```

This result in a PDF file where the pages are images instead of text.

Alternatively, if your system supports printing of TIFF files try to print it directly.

There is also the option of `pdf2ps` for converting PDF to PS, which if works, would likely be preferable.

Comment: Works great! Also `pdf2ps`.

Comment: @DimitriSchachmann: Good. Also note that one have pdf2svg if one want vectorized documents.

Comment: Nice. After `pdf2ps my.pdf my.ps` and then `ps2pdf my.ps mynew.pdf`,  `mynew.pdf` still contains the text in `my.pdf`, i.e. it is not rasterized. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I did it the way [Dimitri](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/112020/dimitri-schachmann) described in the [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198712/how-can-i-rasterize-all-of-the-text-in-a-pdf#comment335896_198918) by using `pdf2ps` and `ps2pdf`.

First I converted my pdf to a `.ps` format by using the command

```
pdf2ps my_file.pdf my_file.ps
```

And then converted it back to pdf format by

```
ps2pdf my_file.ps my_file.pdf
```

This way I got a rasterized version of the original pdf where the content is actually an image. Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, just a reminder that `pdf2ps` and `ps2pdf` are from the ghostscript, so probably need to install ghostscript if your system doesn't come with it.

Comment: This solution does not guarantee that the PDF will be rasterized! Although sometimes the PDF is indeed rasterized.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

The following code rasterizes `a.pdf` → `c.pdf` at 1200 DPI, by initially rasterize at 2400 DPI then downscale by 2 before output. [Documentation](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Devices.html#pdf).

```bash
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfimage24 -r2400 -dDownScaleFactor=2 -o c.pdf a.pdf
```

If you only need to print black and white, you can replace `pdfimage24` with `pdfimage8` in order to speed up.

## Benchmark

As can be seen, the solution above is the fastest, only lose to `pdf2ps` + `ps2pdf` (but `pdf2ps` + `ps2pdf` is **not guaranteed** to rasterize the file), and to `pdf2ppm` (but convert to `.jpg` enlarge the file)

| Solution | Time taken (s) | Memory taken (KiB) | Output file size (KiB) | Printing time (s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `pdftoppm` (1200) (`.jpg`) + `img2pdf` (†) | 2.710 | 603092 | 10341.3 |  |
| `pdf2ps` + `ps2pdf` with temporary file ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/634170/296692)) (*) | 4.110 | 37596 | 1706.4 |  |
| `pdfimage8` (1200) | 4.180 | 35668 | 2348.6 | 9.5 |
| `pdfimage24` (1200/2) | 5.020 | 36088 | 1971.9 | 9.7 |
| `pdfimage24` (1200) | 6.520 | 36212 | 3316.1 |  |
| `pdf2ps` + `ps2pdf` with pipe (*) | 7.230 | 37668 | 1706.4 |  |
| `convert` (600) | 9.560 | 964532 | 5953.6 |  |
| `pdftoppm` (1200) (`.tiff`) + `img2pdf` (†) | 10.850 | 1539512 | 14483.3 |  |
| `convert` (600) + `gs` to optimize ([source](https://superuser.com/a/1588781/577463)) | 12.010 | 964532 | 1989.4 | 9.9 |
| `pdfimage8` (2400/2) | 20.350 | 43872 | 3481.9 |  |
| `pdfimage24` (2400/2) | 23.510 | 46484 | 4833.2 | 15.8 |
| `pdftoppm` (1200) (`.png`) + `img2pdf` ([source](https://superuser.com/a/1490924/577463)) (†) | 33.000 | 626896 | 14127.2 |  |

(*): Solution doesn't actually always rasterize PDF, but `gs` may decide to do that in some (it's unknown in which case it will, probably the cases where the PDF is too complicated) cases.

(†): the code as written will only work for 1-page PDF file, but it can be adapted.

## Details of benchmarked solutions

### `pdftoppm` (1200) (`.jpg`) + `img2pdf` (†)

```bash
pdftoppm -progress -r 1200 -jpeg a.pdf a
img2pdf a-1.jpg -o c.pdf
```

### `pdf2ps` + `ps2pdf` with temporary file ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/634170/296692)) (*)

```bash
gs -sDEVICE=ps2write -dNOCACHE -sOutputFile=c.ps -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE a.pdf
ps2pdf c.ps c.pdf
```

### `pdfimage8` (1200)

```bash
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfimage8 -r1200 -o c.pdf a.pdf
```

### `pdfimage24` (1200/2)

```bash
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfimage24 -r1200 -dDownScaleFactor=2 -o c.pdf a.pdf
```

### `pdfimage24` (1200)

```bash
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfimage24 -r1200 -o c.pdf a.pdf
```

### `pdf2ps` + `ps2pdf` with pipe (*)

```bash
gs -sDEVICE=ps2write -dNOCACHE -sOutputFile=- -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE a.pdf -c quit | ps2pdf - c.pdf
```

### `convert` (600)

```bash
convert -density 600 a.pdf c.pdf
```

### `pdftoppm` (1200) (`.tiff`) + `img2pdf` (†)

```bash
pdftoppm -progress -r 1200 -tiff a.pdf a
img2pdf a-1.tif -o c.pdf
```

### `convert` (600) + `gs` to optimize ([source](https://superuser.com/a/1588781/577463))

```bash
convert -density 600 a.pdf b.pdf
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -sOutputFile=c.pdf b.pdf   -q
```

### `pdfimage8` (2400/2)

```bash
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfimage8 -r2400 -dDownScaleFactor=2 -o c.pdf a.pdf
```

### `pdfimage24` (2400/2)

```bash
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfimage24 -r2400 -dDownScaleFactor=2 -o c.pdf a.pdf
```

### `pdftoppm` (1200) (`.png`) + `img2pdf` ([source](https://superuser.com/a/1490924/577463)) (†)

```bash
pdftoppm -progress -r 1200 -png a.pdf a
img2pdf a-1.png -o c.pdf
```

Source code of the benchmark can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/user202729/f9a81a9cdc1bd7b2f7d06b8465fcbe19).

Comment: Unfortunately, [there's no way to merge questions across different sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4708/388243), so I have to post this answer both here and [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1826641/577463).

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198918/377345) should cover most use cases. However, I found myself in the situation that I wanted to rasterize *to a specific resolution*. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1490924) to a similar question introduced me to the tool `pdftoppm` which yielded the best quality results.

A simple usage example would be

```
pdftoppm input.pdf output -tiff
```

which results in files named `output-X.tif`, where `X` corresponds to the page number of the PDF file.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! But how do you specify the resolution?